# get image dimensions in javascript (using async/await)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to read the image dimensions in JS, but I face strange behaviours that I don't understand. I have 3 **Log-Console**, and the one that I read the image properties is always executed after the contents are loaded (this is supposed to get executed the first), so practically I take always 0,0 of the dimensions in the first run.

```
var data_indexed = createDataSource(data_array);
console.log("third console - ", data_indexed)
function createDataSource(arr){
          var data = [];
          for (var j=1;j<arr.length;j++){
            var imgWidth1=0;
            var imgHeight1=0;
            //start to value 1 to ignore the id
            if (arr[j].search("static")==0){
              var getDimensions = async (url) => {
                const img = new Image();
                img.src = url;
                await img.decode();  
                return img;
              };
              getDimensions(arr[j]).then(img => {
                imgHeight1 = img.naturalHeight
                imgWidth1 = img.naturalWidth
                console.log("first console - ",imgHeight1,imgWidth1);
              });
              console.log("second console - ",imgHeight1,imgWidth1);
              data.push(
                {
                  src: `${arr[j]}`,
                  width: imgWidth1,
                  height: imgHeight1,
                  alt: `image ${j}`,
                },)
            }
          } 
          return data;
        }
```

**Here is the result:**
[image]

**Modified function after woodendoors7 and William replay (maybe this will help newbie gangs)**

```
        (async()=>{
          var data_indexed = await createDataSource(data_array);
          console.log("third console - ", data_indexed)
          })()
        async function createDataSource(arr){
          var data = [];
          for (var j=1;j<arr.length;j++){
            //start to value 1 to ignore the id
            if (arr[j].search("static")==0){
              var imgWidth1 = 0;
              var imgHeight1 = 0;
              var getDimensions = async (url) => {
                const img = new Image();
                img.src = url;
                await img.decode();
                return img;
              };

              let img = await getDimensions(arr[j]);
              imgHeight1 = img.naturalHeight;
              imgWidth1 = img.naturalWidth;
              console.log("first console - ", imgHeight1, imgWidth1);
              console.log("second console - ", imgHeight1, imgWidth1);
              data.push(
                {
                  src: `${arr[j]}`,
                  width: imgWidth1,
                  height: imgHeight1,
                  alt: `image ${j}`,
                },)
            }
            
          } 
          return data;
        }
```

Comment: is there a reason you didn't use await instead of .then? .then of course won't cause the code to wait for a response before moving on.

Comment: Thnx Kevin, I will take a look, I thought the await inside the getDimension would do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that instead of waiting for the image to load, you continue to the second console.log, and `.then` executes afterwards. To fix this, you need to make your top level function async, so `async function createDataSource(url)` and then await the function, which will cause your code first to wait for the image to get loaded and decoded.

```js
let img = await getDimensions(arr[j])
let imgHeight1 = img.naturalHeight;
let imgWidth1 = img.naturalWidth;

console.log("first console - ",imgHeight1,imgWidth1);
```

This will now trigger the variable assignments and console.log only after the getDimensions function is finished running.

`await`-ing a function is preferrable to using .then, since it makes the code much cleaner.

And for the third console to run third, you need to await the createDataSource call too: you need to wrap the call and console log in an async function like so:

```js
(async()=>{
    var data_indexed = await createDataSource(data_array);
    console.log("third console - ", data_indexed)
})()
```

Comment: Excellent explanation, that's what I was looking for. I was almost ready to give up and serve the dimensions from the backend.

Comment: Glad I could be of help! It's best to adopt the async/await syntax for everything. `.then` is useful when for example you want the code to continue and not wait for a function call to finish, and you want to run other things separarely once it does. Otherwise, async/await all the way :)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code and get message on console like this

> second console - 0 0

> first console - 48 48

```
var getDimensions = async (url) => {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = url;
        await img.decode();
        return img;
      };
      var imgWidth1 = 0;
      var imgHeight1 = 0;
      getDimensions("./image.png").then((img) => {
        imgHeight1 = img.naturalHeight;
        imgWidth1 = img.naturalWidth;

        console.log("first console - ", imgHeight1, imgWidth1);
      });
      console.log("second console - ", imgHeight1, imgWidth1);
```

I've changed the code like this.

```
  (async () => {
    var getDimensions = async (url) => {
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = url;
      await img.decode();
      return img;
    };
    var imgWidth1 = 0;
    var imgHeight1 = 0;
    var img = await getDimensions("./image.png");
    imgHeight1 = img.naturalHeight;
    imgWidth1 = img.naturalWidth;
    console.log("first console - ", imgHeight1, imgWidth1);
    console.log("second console - ", imgHeight1, imgWidth1);
  })();
```

The main reason which makes you confusion is that async function and await.
As you've mentioned we could get image dimension after image is loaded.

> console.log("second console - ",imgHeight1,imgWidth1);

This is called first than the code in then clause of getDimension() function since getDimension() is async function.
we could get image dimensions after calling  await on getDimension() function.

Hope this would be helped!

Comment: Thank you, William, however I'm having the same result, the "third-console" is excecuted before the consoles inside await() function. I will get back tomorrow again in your code, I'm totally overwhelmed now.

Comment: in your case, you should make createDataSource function async.
and after calling await createDataSource(), third log would be placed after two preceed

hope you focus on calling async function on my code.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers concerning the placement of keywords `async` and `await` are correct. This answer just offers a simpler alternative.

When the "load" event fires on the `Window Object`, the page is completely loaded, which means all `<img>`s have been loaded. At that point `getDimensions()` can be called.

BTW, what does `.decode()` do?

**Details are commented in example**

```js
function getDimensions() {
  /**
   * document.images collects all <img>s on the page into a HTMLCollection.
   * Array.from() converts the HTMLCollection into an Array.
   * .map() executes a function on each <img> and returns a new array of 
   * each return.
   */
  return Array.from(document.images).map((img, idx) => {
    // Assign "alt" attribute as current index to current <img>.
    img.alt = idx;
    // Return an Object with current <img> property values.
    return {
      src: img.src,
      width: img.naturalWidth,
      height: img.naturalHeight,
      alt: img.alt
    };
  });
}
// Run getDimensions() when page is completely loaded, log the results.
window.onload = e => console.log(getDimensions());
```

```html
<img src="https://loremflickr.com/120/90">
<img src="https://loremflickr.com/160/120">
<img src="https://loremflickr.com/240/180">
```

Comment: about decode(), all I know is if I remove it, the code returns the dimensions only for the first image. There are a lot of threads about this matter, and for sure there are simpler solutions. My images are served from backed into JS and then loaded into DOM, for this case I need all dimensions before loading the images. My poor JS skills made it hard to apply async/await correctly. I was checking tutorials, but I was not able to fix it because most of them show a basic usage and I thought async/await that I was applying inside the function were enough to do the job.